# Cannot import module from another pod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, xcode8, google-fabric

I'm trying to make an analytics provider for Fabric Answers and Firebase for this open-source swift analytics abstraction: https://github.com/nikans/Analytical/ (that's a fork from @Legoless).

The thing is, Fabric comes as a static library, so for a reason not entirely clear to me, I can't include it as a dependency in a podspec. Looks like same thing for Firebase.

But ok, I just included my part of the component [in a subspec (GitHub)](https://github.com/nikans/Analytical/blob/answers-provider/Analytical.podspec) and the component itself [looks like this (GitHub)](https://github.com/nikans/Analytical/blob/answers-provider/Analytical/Classes/Provider/AnswersProvider.swift)

So I'm trying to import Fabric & Answers in this module and these frameworks are included in the project, where I test this. But for some reason, Fabric is found in my app target, but not in my pod.

Pod:
[image]

Project:

[image]

Please can you clarify, what am I losing here?

I tried to set up stuff like Header Search Paths for no avail.
Thanks.

Comment: do you try with `pod install` or `pod update`?

Comment: Well of course) I installed my own pod that way, anyway)

Comment: Can you let me know if cleaning your project helps? Also is the run script build phase in place?

Comment: Cleaning didn't help. Also the config for pods is default and working for a standard project. Everything in my app target works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Add 'Fabric' as dependency in Analytical.podspec

Pod::Spec.new do |s|

---

---

s.dependency 'Fabric'

end

Comment: Missing editing